# Average Length of Text String in Excel Array

Tags: excel

Using the LEN() function it seems simple enough to check the lengths of multiple cells and then take the average.  While this works well for a small number of cells (e.g. AVERAGE(LEN(A1),LEN(A2))) it doesn't scale very well.  I was wondering if there was a way (maybe using an array formula) to have Excel take the average (or apply any numeric formula really) of multiple cells at once.  For example, I was wondering if something like AVERAGE(LEN(A1:A1000)) would be possible.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's possible: use `=AVERAGE(LEN(A1:A1000))` with array entry (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

Comment: or if you'd like to take into account only _non empty_ cells: `=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A1000<>"",LEN(A1:A1000)))` also with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments above, you can use your formula:

```
=AVERAGE(LEN(A1:A1000))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

If you don't like to take into account empty cells, use:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A1000<>"",LEN(A1:A1000)))
```

also with array entry.

Comment: Thanks, I realized shortly after writing that this was an error with how I was entering the formula!

Answer (score 0):

I would create an adjacent column to hold the LENs for each, and run the AVERAGE based on THOSE cells.  You can always collapse the LEN cells if you don't want them visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array formula:

```
=SUM(LEN(A1:A1000))/1000
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

*This will not be accurate if there are blank cells in the range.*

Comment: Interesting. I tried my way and this way, and they both produce the same results. So this is correct as well.  My only objection is how the number of rows is hardcoded in there.

Comment: @durbnpoisn  **your way is probably better if the range contains blanks**